Swift Json Decoder how to get a nested part of the object without decoding it
I receive server response which contains geojson I need to have the geojson as string and don't want to decode it, but this code throws type mismatch exception.
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    id_s = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id_s)
    name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    description = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .description)
    area_type = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .area_type)
    active = String(try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .active))
    danger = String(try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .danger))
    scheduled_from = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .scheduled_from)
    scheduled_to = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .scheduled_to)
    
    let geojsonString = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .geojson)
    // I need the raw geojson string, not a decoded dictionary
    // I get "Expected to decode String but found a dictionary instead"
}

I tried  let geojson = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .geojson) and et geojson = try container.decode(\[String, Any\].self, forKey: .geojson)

How about decoding it as a dictionary and then converting it to a string later with JSONSerialization?

container.decode([String: Any].self, forKey: .geojson) -> [String: Any] and Any is not codeable.

They meant you should use JSONSerialization instead of JSONDecoder. Or you can decode it as normal and then encode the selected part

Maybe you should explain why you want to do this and there might be an alternative solution that is better.
